# helper show the html as a string asp.net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, helper

I am working on asp.net MVC 5, I created a helper for boolean.

I wrote this:

```
public class CustomHelper
    {
        public static string Boolean(bool? value)
        {
            if(value == true )
                return string.Format("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok green'></span>");
            else
                return string.Format("<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove red'></span>");
        }
    }
```

and the Razor is:

```
<td>
     @CustomHelper.Boolean(item.Deleted)
</td>
```

but the result is the same as the photo. the html appears as a string 
[image]

how to fix it? so I can show the symbol instead? 
thank you

Comment: please a little explination, I did not understand what do you mean

Comment: Use MvcHtmlString.Create instead of string.format

Comment: And your helper is not an extension to MVC helpers it's just a class that has a method. Check mvc helpers concept in asp.net site

Comment: it works, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the @ symbol encodes the output.
You should create your custom check as an extension method to the `HtmlHelper` class as below

```
    public static class BooleanExtensions
         {
              public static MvcHtmlString Boolean(this HtmlHelper helper, bool value)
              {
                  var spanTag = new TagBuilder("span");
                  if(value)
                     spanTag.MergeAttribute("class", glyphicon glyphicon-ok green");
                  else
                     spanTag.MergeAttribute("class", glyphicon glyphicon-remove red");

                   return MvcHtmlString.Create(spanTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));           

              }
         }
```

Next, in your Razor view, call it as:

```
@Html.Boolean(item.Deleted)
```

Don't forget to add the @using for the namespace that has the class in the beginning of the view